# Find substring in the string in TWIG

Tags: php, twig, substring, comparison-operators

I want to find substring of the string or check if there is no such substring using Twig. On the words, I need analogue of 'strstr' or 'strpos' in php.
I googled and searched this issue in stackoverflow but nothing found. Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Nothing found, really? When I google `Find substring in the string in TWIG`, I get a [first hit](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/twig-users/50KrckEAkkA) that looks really good. I don't think it's going to get any better than that.

Comment: Please follow the [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) you needed to confirm before posting *any* question. Keep in mind that only you want something and you ask yourself how it is programmed does not qualify as a programming question per-se.

Comment: Pekka, thanks for your link but it isn't exactly what i found. strstr and strpos lets find positions of substring in the string or return false if there is no such substring. It is not similar with strpos.

Comment: If you don't find what you want, you can always [do it yourself](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html).

Answer (score 432, accepted):

Just searched for the [docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc), and found [this](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#containment-operator):

Containment Operator:
The **in** operator performs containment test.
It returns true if the left operand is contained in the right:

```
{# returns true #}

{{ 1 in [1, 2, 3] }}

{{ 'cd' in 'abcde' }}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this inside an if statement?

Comment: Yes, indeed, you can !

Comment: Great :) I used it to figure out the current route: <li class="{% if 'gew_team_default_' in app.request.get('_route') %}active{% endif %}">

Comment: @TobiasOberrauch so did I ; you can also use `app.request.pathinfo` as comparison :)

Comment: Is it affected by slashes or special characters? I am trying to do is find `/some-link` in `some-doma.in/some-link`...

Comment: Just for completeness, the syntax for testing whether a substring is not present is: {% if 'needle' not in haystack %}

Comment: {%- if "☑" in output  -%}
... does not work for me when output is set to 

    ☑<br>(<time datetime="00Z" class="datetime">2019-04-18</time>)