# Correct way to conditionally hide a content block on certain pages

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

What is the best way to hide e.g. a nav bar on certain pages in Timber Twig templates. Have tried wrapping the navbar element in

```
{% if post.title !== 'foo bar' %}
// show the nav
{% endif %}
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `!==` in twig.
You have to use `!=`

Working snippet:
https://twigfiddle.com/9l9lrc

```
{% set var = 'foo bar' %}
{% if var != 'foo bar' %}
    <h2>Nav</h2>
{% else %}
    <em>no-nav</em>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks. Out of interest, is there a way to something like {% if var does does not contain 'string' %}?

Comment: yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007288/find-substring-in-the-string-in-twig