# Find characters in string in TWIG

Tags: php, html, twig

I have this hidden field :

```
<input type="hidden" id="PartNum" name="pn" value="{{ price.getPartNumber }}">
```

And this `input text`

```
<input type="hidden" id="ltid" name="lt" value="{{ price.getLt }}">
```

I want do a test on the value of the `PartNumber` `value="{{ price.getPartNumber }}"`

If it contains this String `35-l0l-1003` I should change the value of the `value="{{ price.getLt }}"` to `30`

I should use `strpbrk` to search a string for any of a set of characters.
I'm beginner in `Twig` and I don't know how can I add it.
Please can you help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find substring in the string in TWIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007288/find-substring-in-the-string-in-twig)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case just use :

```
 {{'Toto' in 'Tototatattiti'}} //Will return true
 {{'Toto' in 'Tata' }} //Will return false
```

However you can add almost every function in Twig. Here is a simple implementation of the `file_exist` function (I'm actually doing it in my Controller core class)

```
    //Getting twig by a loader
    $twig = $this->templating;
    //Getting twig environnement
    $env = $twig->getTwig();
    //Adding the new function
    $fe = new Twig_SimpleFunction('file_exists', 'file_exists');
    $env->addFunction($fe);
```